# Modify workflowModel.xml in Alfresco

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I want to change some data in workflowModel.xml (set the default value of requiredApprovePercent to 100).
Of course I'm not supposed to change the file in tomcat, I need to override it in my eclipse project.

Do I need to register the model in a context file, and in which directory am I supposed to put the file in my eclipse project?

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Do a bit of research, there are a lot of examples....

Answer (score 1):

if you're going to create a custom workflow model you need Alfresco to pick it up when starting. So yesm you need to deploy it with:

```
<bean id="myworkflows.workflowBootstrap" parent="workflowDeployer"> 
<property name="models">
  <list>
     <-- Task Model associated with above process definition -->
     <value>alfresco/workflow/customModel.xml</value>
  </list>
   </property>
   <property name="workflowDefinitions">
  <props>      
     <prop key="engineId">activiti</prop>     
     <prop key="location">alfresco/extension/customModel.bpmn2.0.xml</prop>     
     <prop key="mimetype">text/xml</prop>     
     <prop key="redeploy">false</prop>
  </props>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Or something similar in the context file (tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension is the path where you want your custom files to be.

[This](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/topics/wf-howto.html) is also a great link to start working with workflows in Alfresco.
Hope it helps a little bit.